# How can I view raw content with HTTP request?

Tags: python-3.x, sockets

I cannot seem to make the script print out JUST the content viewed by the page

I would like this to be using sockets module. No other libraries like requests or urllib

I cannot really try much. So I instantly committed a sin and came here first ^^'

My code:

```
import socket

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect(("pastebin.com", 80))
sock.sendall(b"GET /raw/yWmuKZyb HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: pastebin.com\r\n\r\n")
r = sock.recv(4096).decode("utf-8")
print(r)

sock.close()
```

I want the printed result to be:

```
test
test1
test2
test3
```

but what I get is

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 09 Apr 2019 14:20:45 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Set-Cookie: __cfduid=xxx; expires=Wed, 08-Apr-20 14:20:45 GMT; path=/; domain=.pastebin.com; HttpOnly
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
CF-Cache-Status: MISS
Server: cloudflare
CF-RAY: 4c4d1f9f685ece41-LHR

19
test
test1
test2
test3
```

Comment: A *response body* follows the first occurrence of `\r\n\r\n` (The 19 is part of the response) so find that then read past till the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just extract out the content after \r\r\n\n by using string.split and print it

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect(("pastebin.com", 80))
sock.sendall(b"GET /raw/yWmuKZyb HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: pastebin.com\r\n\r\n")
r = sock.recv(4096).decode("utf-8")
#Extract the content after splitting the string on \r\n\r\n
content_list = r.split('\r\n\r\n')[1].split('\r\n')
content = '\r\n'.join(content_list)
print(content)
#19
#test
#test1
#test2
#test3
sock.close()
```

Comment: but this is including the 19 which is part of the response. and I cannot just use the replace function because if I select a different pastebin link including those numbers it would be removed

Comment: I already know about requests and urllib stuff... I want to do it with sockets xD

Comment: Ohh, you want to do it the hard way, rather then using an easy to use library like requests, let me see

Comment: I updated my replace logic, it should work on any other pastebin link. Give it a try and let me know if it doesn't work for it

Comment: still receiving a 19 :/

Comment: Which URL did you try

Comment: wel, I first tried the original link. Then I tried some others and it just says another random number each link

Comment: Can you provide a few URL's you tried for more context

Comment: I just randomly used these just now. Still random numbers https://pastebin.com/raw/tQxBV4uq
https://pastebin.com/raw/yWmuKZyb
https://pastebin.com/raw/LMPeGWXk

Comment: Not sure why are you not using requests, it will make your like much easier, also as per the answer by @steffen-ullrich you would need deep HTTP understanding to figure out where the content you want exactly lies

Comment: Because other languages don't have libraries like requests or URLLIB so learning to do it the manual way will make life easier if I learn another language .-.

Comment: Well if a language like python is giving you tools to make your life easier, I would suggest using it, and lot of other languages do provide you libraries like these

Comment: C, C++ and Java? Ive never seen them with those libraries. I know how to use requests and urllib perfectly fine btw. I just again, wanna learn the manual way

Comment: For Java: http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/ . For C https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/ And these two came up with just simple google search.
Also learning the manual way will need to read the docs pointed out below which is non trivial, if you can do it, go ahead

Comment: Cool, if this answer helped you, please upvote and accept

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a HTTP/1.1 request and therefore the web server might reply with a response body in chunked transfer encoding. In this mode each chunk is prefixed by the size in hexadecimal. You either need to implement this mode or you could simply do a HTTP/1.0 request in which case the server will not use chunked transfer encoding since this was only introduced with HTTP/1.1.

Anyway, if you don't want to use any existing libraries but do your own HTTP it is expected that you actually understand HTTP. Understanding means that you have read the relevant standards, because that's what standards are for. For HTTP/1.1 this is originally [RFC 2616](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html) which was later slightly reworked into RFC 7230-7235. Once you started reading these standards you likely appreciate that there are existing libraries which deal with these protocols, since these are far from trivial.